# Does Conversation Expire if Bot is Restarted?

Tags: botframework

I've been researching how to trigger proactive conversations via Bot Framework. I found good reference in

https://binarygrounds.com/2021/01/21/proactive-messages.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

In both examples User ID and ConversationReference is stored in ConcurrentDictionary. I assume I can implement some hard storage for this data in case the bot is restarted. However, I cannot find anywhere if that conversation reference is still valid if bot is restarted, and how long it is retained in general.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the documentation on [bot state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and [saving user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), this depends on how you as the bot developer decide to implement storage. The second documentation page suggests that you cannot guarantee state continuity even without rebooting, as the bot may run on various machines, or be invoked numerous times by a serverless function.

If you decide to persist user and conversation IDs to some permanent storage (hypothetically let's say it's CosmosDB), then you could retrieve conversation state from CosmosDB that way.

Your best bet would be to assume that the Bot Framework itself will not persist this data for you, and you must do so manually, which means you should be able to define the format.